# gson deserilize byte array to generic type

Tags: java, generics, gson, deserialization

**I know this has been asked before. But the mentioned solutions are not working for me.**

I have the following method

```
public class JsonDesializer<T> implements Deserializer<T> {

    @Override
    public T deserialize(String topic, byte[] data) {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        if (data == null) {
            return null;
        }
        Type typeOfT = new TypeToken<T>(){}.getType();
        var a =  gson.fromJson(new String(data, StandardCharsets.UTF_8), typeOfT);
        return (T) a;
    }
}
```

This is what I found mostly while browsing the internet (which included SO as well).
Unfortunately this returns a **LinkedTreeMap**, something that belongs to gson only. If I inspect the values of this object, these values are present. But the type is not that of T. Attaching a ss of the vs code debug console showing the structure of this treemap.

[image: ss of structure]

The properties in the target class would be patientId, systolicPressure, etc. I have seen solutions where we have to pass TargetClass.class as a constructor parameter.

For eg, if I want to deserialize into a class called BloddPressure then I can pass BloodPressure.class and then I can use that for the type. But the problem with that approach is `A<B>.class` doesn't work.

How to convert this tree map into T which is passed.

Comment: Why would Gson make you pass a `TypeToken` if it could be constructed from `T` alone?

Comment: @shmosel I didn't get what you are saying. I didn't pass `TypeToken`. I am evaluating that myself through `Type typeOfT = new TypeToken<T>(){}.getType();` And that is not working.

Comment: I'm saying you can't construct `TypeToken` with a generic type, otherwise `fromJson()` would have done that internally.

Comment: Ok so if TypeToken is not the way to go is there any way I can deserialize it to generic type? @shmosel

Comment: TypeToken is the way to go, but you have to construct it with an explicit type parameter, like `new TypeToken<List<String>>`.

Comment: Ok let me give this a try

Comment: there is no public constructor for `TypeToken`. only a private and protected. so can't do `new TypeToken<List<String>>`

Comment: Right, you need the whole `() {}`. I shortened it because my point was about the generic type.